# Is being a loan word time limited by the time it was adopted?

Tags: borrowing

Is being a loan word limited by time of adoption?

For example the English word "loci" comes from Latin, as other 60% of English words do. Is it a loan word in English?

Or is it only for "recently added" ones? Like "monitor, print" etc that English gave to other languages recently.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are they called *loan*words if we never intend to pay them back to their original languages?

Comment: @dan04. Now that is a more interesting question.

Comment: _Loci_ is a lot more loan-wordy than _print_, because it’s still **transparently** foreign, whereas _print_ is completely nativised. If you didn’t know it’s from Latin (and most people don’t), you’d think it was just a native, English word. Not so with _loci_.

Answer (score 1):

Any word that entered a language by borrowing is technically a loanword, regardless of how much time has gone by since. Of course, the longer ago a word was borrowed, the less likely speakers are to realize it's a loanword.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really firm with anglophone terminology here, but in German terminology there is a difference between *Lehnwort* and *Fremdwort*.

A *Fremdwort* (literally "foreign word") is a recent borrowing that still has signs of its origin (unusual phonology, unusual inflections, etc.)

A *Lehnwort* (literally "loan word") is a less recent borrowing that shows strong assimilation like complete integration into the native phonology, complete integration into existing grammatical paradigms. Even words borrowed 2000 years ago into German are still called *Lehnwort* (e.g., *Fenster* from Latin *fenestra* "window" or *Mauer* from Latin *murus* "wall")

Comment: Is time really relevant to the distinction? Older loans can retain unusual phonology (nasal vowels in older French loans is the best example I can think of, but I’m sure there are better ones), and brand-new loans can happen to look just like native words and fit the morphology perfectly, but presumably those would still be considered _Fremdwörter_ and _Lehnwörter_, respectively?

Comment: No, time is not the relevant factor, although it correlates with the degree of integration. The retention of foreign phonological features can pose some tricky questions: When is the phonological system of the acceptor language permanently changed by the loans and they are otherwise assimilated?